# Developer mode not working after upgrade to Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4, developer-mode, windows

I've recently upgraded my local installation of Magento from 2.3 to 2.4.3. After doing this, several serious issues have arisen. I'm hoping somebody has experienced similar and found a way to solve these problems.

Every time I made a change to the appearance of the front end, editing a css file for example, I now need to run a setup:static-content:deploy to update the static files and see the changes reflected. Previously when in developer mode, these changes only required a cache:flush. This is obviously very inconvenient when making small changes and then having to wait an eternity to see them!

Furthermore, now when I run a setup:upgrade, all the static files are deleted unless I include the tag --keep-generated

It seems as though developer mode is not turned on although I have checked and it is. As a test I've tried switching to production mode but it fails and reverts to developer mode. I'm fairly sure this issue has occurred because Windows is no longer supported. Has anyone had a similar issue and is there any way to solve this without using Docker or a similar?

Thank you

Jack

Answer (score 1):

first of all magento is not supported in windows and MacOS , please go through this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html).

Best Guess:-

so the issue is static files are not generating in the developer mode automatically which they should do, try checking the URLs of the static files in this path:-

Debugging steps:-

1.Try checking the URL's of the JS files and CSS files in dev tools of your browser and check what is the HTTP code , is it 404 ?

The solution by guess for this type of error:-

```
1.Go toStores->Configuration->General->Web->Base URL's and (Secure) Base URL's
2. Please make that URL as empty and save and again clean the cache and try it.
3. Please note that this solution is recommended to try in a local development environment.
4. Please let me know if this worked.
```

Thanks.

[image]